# How should presentation tier (JSF) interoperate with services tier (Spring)?

Tags: java, architecture, jsf, jakarta-ee

I know that there are many different architectures exist. In this question I consider 3-tiers architecture (presentation-services (busyness logic)-data access layer (DAOs). And I want to concentrate on how presentation tier works with services tier.

The problem I met is standard. I have stateless services layer, and I think it should be stateless for the sake of scalability and performance.
 
I also have stateful presentation layer. For example, when user fills some form and inputed values don't pass validation, it's good practice to show all fields with inputed values and to point to incorrect fields.

So, imagine that we have `FooBean` with methods `setFoo (Foo f)`, `getFoo ()` and `doSave ()`. Bean has *Session scope.* 
And we want to save (persist) new instance of Foo. What we do is call method setFoo () and then call method doSave (). If saving failed than user will see just filled form with all inputed values (getFoo () method is called).

That's nice, but now imagine that user clicks `Create Foo` link, fills all fields, tries to save but doesn't pass validation? He will see filled form again. And then he clicks on 'Create Foo' again (he wants to create 2 Foo objects simultaneously). He will see filled form with pointed errors. But it's bad, because he didn't fill this (second, new) form yet.

If we change FooBean scope to `Request`, than we won't be able to show filled form when it's necessary (after saving failed).

So, what is the way out? What is the correct solution? It can be JSF-specific or general.

Comment: Give me at least one reason not to mark you comment as 'noise, offensive or spam'.

Comment: Because he has some point ;) Although 48% isn't alwfully bad, it might drive people away from your questions, deeming you "ungrateful", for example.

Comment: speaking strictly, there is a button "this answer is useful" as well, which also seems a bit unemployed.

Comment: @Bozho: Well, I think that 'correct answer ticket' is here not for the sake of appreciation but rather for those people who will find this question later (from google or from local search). When I want to show that I appreciate an answer I usually write correspondent comment. I also can vote for that answer. But that's all I can do here.

Comment: while you have a point, I doubt you didn't get an appropriate answer in 50% of the cases. Commenting is no way of showing appreciation. Voting is, but you don't have too much upvotes either.

Comment: @Bozho: hm.. for me commenting is. why do you care so much about your rate? 
About difference between commenting and voting up: I leave a comment to all useful answers, but I vote up only that answers usefulness of which is related to the described problem. For example, I don't know if your answer is really about described problem until I open your links and google some related information.

Comment: Yes, you are right to vote after knowing it is a good one.
But it's not that anyone is caring too much about their rates, rather than it being the idea behind this site, and most of the community follows that idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something called "conversation". There are a number of ways for achieving this.:

- [MyFaces orchestra](http://myfaces.apache.org/orchestra/index.html)
- [JBoss seam](http://www.redhat.com/docs/manuals/jboss/jboss-eap-4.2/doc/seam/Seam_Reference_Guide/Conversations_and_workspace_management-Seams_conversation_model.html)

A conversation is either automatically or manually managed scope that is greater than a request, but is smaller than a session. Ideally it should store your beans as long as they are needed to be stored - i.e. in one *conversation*. So from your example, the first conversation will end at the point the use navigates away from the first page.

MyFaces orchestra (I can't tell for seam) can also differentiate between different browser windows/tabs.

Comment: One more way I found is to use Spring WebFlow. But in my project I used MyFaces orchestra. A big plus of orchestra is that only few things should be added/changed in the project to integrate Orchestra.